# using directive with whole program scope

Tags: c#

How can I have a using directive that has a scope of the whole program instead of just the file it is in. For every module that I use I would only want to set this once. If there is no way to do this what is the workaround to get this to work.

I thought about putting them all into a header file but C sharp does not have a file include.

Comment: No such thing in C#. VB.Net has/had project level `Imports` (the equivalent) but C# never has.

Comment: Put the whole program in one file; problem solved.

Comment: @EricLippert - nice. Also, just spotted this in the question "If there is no way to do this what is the workaround to get this to work." - which boils down to - if there's no way to do this, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Fortunately.

Just wondering why you want to do this. This would be a bad programming habit anyway - put concerns and dependencies only when you really need them. If you add the same using directives everywhere, you also need the referenced assemblies everywhere, something you really don't want to do. Your project should rely on assemblies it needs, no more, no less.

Your argument about wasting time is a bit strange; if you loose so much time, you might have another problem in your architecture.

Note: [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Usage_Scenarios__Optimizing_Using_Directives.html) is a tool that you may find useful.

Comment: If file1.cs is using List<T> and file2.cs is using List<T> I have to add using System.Collections.Generic; to both of the files. In C I would make a h file that has all the #includes the program is using and then just include that file in all of the .c files.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but what you are trying to achieve is not possible and I don't think that there are any workarounds. This is supported for example in WebForms or Razor views where you could declare common namespaces in the `<namespaces>` section of your web.config but unfortunately such artifact doesn't exist for standard C# files.

Comment: I am disappointed that this can not be done but thank you for your reply anyway. I can not believe a modern language can not handle something that could be done in a 40 year old language. Maintaining these directives in every file is going to waste a significant amount of time.

Comment: Personally I don't feel that this is something that has wasted my time. Modern IDEs and plugins such as Resharper can automatically handle (add, arrange, ...) all using directives in an entire solution.

Comment: Just because it could be done in a 40 year old language doesn't mean that it's a good thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Having the `using` directives in each single `.cs` file allows you to take that file out of an existing project and drop it into another project, provided it has the same references.

Also, adding `using` directives is basically automatic at this point. My tool of choice, [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Place the cursor on whatever class isn't recognized, press Alt+Enter, and the `using` directive gets added automatically. If there are multiple choices, you get to pick the right one.